# How do I get gvim/vim to open a file in a path with non-ascii characters?

Tags: vim, character-encoding, path

At first I had this path to one of my files in Windows:

```
C:\mine\NOTES
```

I  renamed it such that the last part of the path i.e 'NOTES' had the `U+2588 FULL BLOCK=solid`
before and after it. I inserted the character using the key combination ALT+219(alt code) which is an extended ascii drawing character. I did this so that the folder could stand out from the 20 plus folders in the directory. At this point, I'm quite happy that it looks cool and does stand out. However, when the files in the folder using a text editor all hell breaks loose. These are the results when I try to open the file `scheme_notes.scm` in different editors:

```
path="C:\mine\&#brevbar NOTES &#brevbar"
```

(The solid character is rendered as a `&#brevbar` character instead of a solid block.

GVIM prints:

```
"path" [New directory]`
"path" E212: Can't open file for writing.
```

Python(IDLE) opens the file but does not display the contents which the file has and prints the following error when you try to run it(I know it's not a python file, I was testing)

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\mine\\\xa6 NOTES \xa6\\python_notes.py'
```

(The `\xa6` is a `&#brevbar` character)

Pspad does not allow you to edit the file:

```
File has set attributes: Hidden ReadOnly System
Save Changes Made to File?`
```

Scite displays a dialog saying:

```
Cannot save under this name. Save under different name?
```

If you click yes, the dialog keeps popping up repeatedly. I had to kill the program using
powershell after there were 15 plus dialogs on the window.(and it hadn't stopped)

Jedit prints:

```
The following I/O operation could not be completed:
Cannot save: "path" (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Netbeans:

```
Failed to set current directory to "path" The system cannot find the file
specified.
```

I want Vim to be able to open the file without resorting to renaming the folder. Does vim have a setting for opening paths with unicode characters?

I'm asking this because python was able to change to that directory when I did this:

```
import os
os.chdir(u"\u2588 NOTES \u2588")
os.listdir('.')`<br> `==> ['scheme_notes.scm','python_struff.py']
```